# android_alarm_manager_plus not triggering callback

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

Followed the example instructions for this plugin successfully but only the FIRST debug session... So I know it CAN work.
Now, I get no error but the alarm is never triggered ?!? Traced into the plugin and no error there. You are my last resort, google did not provide solution and I don't have any hair left to pull...

Debuging on my connected device:
Samsung model SM-J120W
Android version 6.0.1

**android_alarm_manager_plus 1.0.1**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
...
<service
  android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
  android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
  android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
  android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
  android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
  android:enabled="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in main.dart:

```
// top level function is never called :-(
void callback() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=$isolateId function='$callback'");
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  bool test = await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  print('initialize test = $test'); // **_returns true_**
  ...
}
```

in my home page:

```
Center(
  child: Switch(
  value: isOn,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      isOn = value;
    });
    if (isOn == true) {
      AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), alarmId, **callback**, startAt: DateTime.now(), exact: true, wakeup: true)
          .then((value) => print('Alarm Timer Started = $value')); // **_returns true_**
    } else {
      AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(alarmId).then((value) => print('Alarm Timer Canceled = $value'));
    }
  },
)),
```

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Is there any missing information that I can provide ?

Thanks for any help/sugestion you can provide !

Comment: First session means? It only fire once and never again right?

Comment: No it means it worked only the first time I debugged this code... three days ago ! Weird !

Comment: Just try uninstalling your app from phone do `flutter clean` build again. Because I just run their example and its working fine.

Comment: Running their example again, now gives me errors...

E/flutter ( 6675): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
E/flutter ( 6675):
This example is using older plugin versions. If I "upgrade" I get tons of errors... :-(

Comment: Have you tried cloning their repository example? Try cloning and run their example.

Comment: Here is a GitHub project with plain Flutter Sample app with the code I use: 

https://github.com/mpoirier101/AlarmTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update AndroidManifest.xml with the service code below:

```
<service
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```